# how to dynamically update collection with $inc command

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, loops, mongojs

I have this mongo collection `opponents` to store each player's opponents details

```
{username:foo, foo:{foo1:0,foo2:0,foo3:0}} 
{username:foo1,foo1:{foo:0,foo2:0,foo3:0}}
{username:foo2,foo2:{foo:0,foo1:0,foo3:0}}//i.e player foo2 play 0 games with foo,foo1 and foo3
```

And this `table`object in the node.js server side:

```
 var table =[{name:"foo",rounds:3},{name:"foo1",rounds:3},{name:"foo2",rounds:3},{name:"foo3",rounds:3}] //all players' name in a table with their rounds number
```

For each player in a table, I want to append their opponents' names and rounds to the `opponent` collection accordingly(of course no need to append themselves).The desired results is:

```
{username:foo, foo:{foo1:3,foo2:3,foo3:3}}
{username:foo1,foo1:{foo:3,foo2:3,foo3:3}}
{username:foo2,foo2:{foo:3,foo1:3:foo3:3}}
{username:foo3,foo3:{foo:3,foo1:3,foo2:3}}
```

I have a custom function `fun(name)` to return each player an array of their opponents names. so `fun(table[0].name)` would return `[foo1,foo2,foo3]`

```
function fun(name){
  var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <players.length; i++){
       if(players[i].name!=name){
         result.push(players[i].name)
         }
      }
        return result;
 }
```

This is my current code:

```
     for (var i =0;i<table.length;i++){
      db.opponents.update({username:table[i].name},{$inc:{[table[i].name + '.' + fun(table[i].name)[0] ] :table[i].rounds}})
      if (table.length>2){
      db.opponents.update({username:table[i].name},{$inc:{[table[i].name + '.' + fun(table[i].name)[1] ] :table[i].rounds}})
    }
     if (table.length>3){
      db.opponents.update({username:table[i].name},{$inc:{[table[i].name + '.' + fun(table[i].name)[2] ] :table[i].rounds}}) 
    }
```

But it is rigid hard-coding, if the `table.length` increase I would need more line of code. How can I use variable to make it more compact? I tried to use nested loop but that made it even worse.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

```
for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
   db.opponents.update({username:table[i].name},{$inc:{[table[i].name + '.' + fun(table[i].name)[0] ] :table[i].rounds}})
    for (var j = 1;j<fun(table[i].name).length;j++){
      db.opponents.update({username:table[i].name},{$inc:{[table[i].name + '.' + fun(table[i].name)[j] ] :table[i].rounds}})
     }
  }
```